# Reversing byte input with basic assembly code

Tags: algorithm, assembly, byte, reverse

I'm participating in a ctf where one task is to reverse a row of input bytes using an assembly-ish environment. The input is x bytes long and the last byte is always 0x00. One example would be :

Input 4433221100, output 0011223344

I'm thinking that a loop that loops until it reaches input 00 is a place to start.

Do any of you have a suggestion on how to approach this? I don't need specific code examples, but some advice to point me in the right direction would be great. I only have basic alu operations, jumps and conditional jumps, storing and reading memory addresses, and some other basic stuff available. All alu operations are mod 256.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, finding the length by searching for the `0` byte to find the end / length is one way to start.  Depending on where you want the destination, it's possible to copy in the same loop that searches for the end.

If you want to **reverse in-place**, you need to find the end first (with a separate loop).  Then you can load from both ends, store registers to opposite locations, and walk your pointers inward until they cross, standard in-place reverse that you can find examples of anywhere.

---

If you want **make a reversed *copy* into other space, you could do it in one pass over the source** (without finding the length first).  Store output starting from the end of a buffer, decrementing the output pointer as you increment the read pointer.  When you're done, you have a pointer to the start of the reversed copy, which you can pass to an output function.  You won't know where you're going to stop, so the buffer needs to be big enough.  But since you're just passing the pointer to another function, it's fine that you don't know (until you're done copying) where the start of the reversed copy will be.

You could still separately find the length and then copy, but that would be pointlessly inefficient.

---

**If you need the reversed copy to start at some known position in another buffer (e.g. to append to another string or array)**, you *would* need the length or a pointer to the end before you store anything, so it's a 2-pass operation like reversing in-place.

You can then read the source backwards and write the destination forwards (or "output" each byte 1 at a time to some IO stream).  Your loop termination condition could be a down-counter or a pointer compare using a pointer in a register, comparing src against the already-known start of the source or dst against the calculated end of the destination.

Or you can read the source forwards until you reach the position you found for the end, storing in reverse order starting from the calculated end of where the destination should go.

(If your machine is like 6502 and can easily index into a static array, but not easily keep a whole pointer in a register, obviously you'll want to use indices that count from 0.  That makes detecting the start even easier, like sub reg, 1 / jnz if subtract already sets flags for a conditional branch to test.)

Answer (score 2):

```
save your stackpointer in a variable

for each byte of the string 
push byte onto the stack
repeat if byte was <> 0

pull byte from stack
output byte
repeat until old_stackpointer is reached
```

in 6502 assembler this could look like

```
   tsx
   stx OLD_STACKPTR

   ldy#$ff
loop:
   iny
   lda INPUT,y
   pha
   bne loop

   ldy#$ff
loop2:
   iny
   pla 
   sta INPUT,y
   tsx
   cpx OLD_STACKPTR 
   bne loop2
```

Comment: Is that really faster on 6502 than just scanning to find the length and then copying like in my answer?  I would have though making an extra temporary copy would be at least a bit slower.  I know 6502 has limitations on pointers / indexing, but does that make it hard to read an array in one direction and write another array in another direction in the same loop?  I guess you'd need two separate index registers or else it would cost extra instructions in the loop to swap things into `y`.

Comment: The problem is, that you have to find the end (Byte 0) first, if you want to have 1 incrementing and 1 decrementing pointer.
This would look like

ldy #$00


ldx #PositionOfByte0


lda INPUT,y


sta INPUT,x


But the search for PositionOfByte0 costs time. So there won't be much speed improvement.

Comment: Right, my answer on this question discusses the rare case when it's possible to do it in one pass.  But is there any speed *advantage* to using `n` bytes of extra stack space that weren't necessary?  Like is `pla` (4 cycles) faster than `lda INPUT,x` / `dex`?  Decrementing an input index toward zero let you `bne` on that, instead of a clunky `tsx` / `cpx` to compare the stack pointer, so avoiding the stack should be a net saving.  (Although that optimization could be done even with your stack-pointer strategy: use x as a down-counter, starting from the y your first loop found.)